# Show next sibling element if is previous element hovered with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this snippet of `html`

```css
ul { display:none }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="hh-a-1 mm-listitem">test 1</a>
<a href="#" class="hh-a-1 mm-listitem">test 2</a>
<a href="#" class="hh-a-1 mm-listitem">test 3</a>
<ul class="hh-ul-1 mm-listitem">
  <a href="#" class="hh-a-2 mm-listitem__text">sub 1</a>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="hh-a-1 mm-listitem">Test 4</a>
<ul class="hh-ul-1 mm-listitem">
  <a href="#" class="hh-a-2 mm-listitem__text">sub 2</a>
</ul>
```

By default `ul` elements are hidden.

I'm trying to achieve when the `a` element is hovered to show only `ul` element which is the next sibling.

For example, if `test 3` link has hovered, the `ul` element with `sub 1` link needs to show up and to stay while the `a` and `ul` are hovered.

I'm not so experienced, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

Comment: The only permitted content inside `<ul>` elments are `Zero or more <li>, <script> and <template> elements.` `<a>` is none of them https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)

I add focus so you can keep the UL open

Also the a in the UL should be in an li. That makes it somewhat harder to make a sub-sub menu

```css
ul { display:none; position: absolute; top:50px }

a:hover + ul { display: block }

a:focus + ul { display: block }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="hh-a-1 mm-listitem">test 1</a>
<a href="#" class="hh-a-1 mm-listitem">test 2</a>
<a href="#" class="hh-a-1 mm-listitem">test 3</a>
<ul class="hh-ul-1 mm-listitem">
  <li><a href="#" class="hh-a-2 mm-listitem__text">sub 1</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="hh-a-1 mm-listitem">Test 4</a>
<ul class="hh-ul-1 mm-listitem">
  <li><a href="#" class="hh-a-2 mm-listitem__text">sub 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: :focus -> :hover  

Comment: @Amoong I used focus to keep the menu open - hover is added

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks~!

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, it is showing now, thanks. But it disappears as soon as I move the mouse from the `a` element. It should disappear only when I move the mouse from the `a` and the `ul` as well. The `a` inside the `ul` needs to be clickable. In this case, it is not possible to click on it because it disappears as soon as you move the mouse from the `a`

Comment: Click the a, to keep the ul open - that is what the focus is for. If you want a drop down menu, please do not write one yourself since there are million better ones out there